# Why the new key-value pair is not getting added to the existing array after parsing the array through foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, key-value

I've following array titled `$aFriends` as follows :
The actual array is very large but for reference I've printed only first two elements here.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dob_setting] => 4
            [user_id] => 1
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_server_id] => 0
            [user_name] => admin
            [full_name] => admin
            [gender] => 1
            [user_image] => 2015/03/96cc42b833bc0d34b521818272c05011%s.jpg
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 1
            [language_id] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dob_setting] => 0
            [user_id] => 30
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_server_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-30
            [full_name] => 
            [gender] => 0
            [user_image] => 
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 7
            [language_id] => 
        )
)
```

I want to add a key as follows to every element of above array :

```
$aFriends[0]['profile_image'] = image_creator($aFriends[$key][$value]['user_image']);
$aFriends[1]['profile_image'] = image_creator($aFriends[$key][$value]['user_image']);
.
.
.
.
.
```

For it I tried following code :

```
foreach($aFriends as $key => $value) {
          $aFriends[$key][$value]['profile_image'] = image_creator($aFriends[$key][$value]['user_image']);    

        }
```

Got the same array as output. Not adding new key `['profile_image']` to each element. Please help me in getting the desired array.

Thanks.

Comment: `$value` is just another array. You should've gotten mass warnings... You probably mean `$aFriends[$key]['profile_image'] = '';` ?

Comment: @Raphioly-San:Please see the updated question and then answer it.

Comment: `$aFriends[$key]['profile_image'] = image_creator($aFriends[$key]['user_image']);` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($aFriends as $key => $value) {
      $aFriends[$key][$value]['profile_image'] = image_creator($aFriends[$key][$value]['user_image']);    
}
```

$value is an array, why you put it there?

```
foreach($aFriends as $key => $value) {
      $aFriends[$key]['profile_image'] = image_creator($aFriends[$key]['user_image']);    
}
```

Comment: see my comment ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
foreach($aFriends as $friend => $values) {
    $aFriends[$friend]['profile_image'] = '';
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't... `$friend` should be passed by ref, but it isn't here. Plus pass by ref in a foreach is not done...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write `[$value]` in the body of loop

Your `foreach` loop should be like this

```
foreach($aFriends as $key => $value) {
      $aFriends[$key]['profile_image'] = image_creator($aFriends[$key]['user_image']);    
}
```